# CMake: Make a static library works but dynamic doesn't

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I am trying to make a shared library using CMake, but its wired that if I make it statically, it works well, but dynamic doesn't:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.6)
PROJECT(TestDemo)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)

# Headers
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(src)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(src/xxx)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(3rdparty/zstd)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/include)

# CORE LIB
FILE(GLOB CORE_SRC src/xxx/*.cpp
        src/xxx/io/*.cpp
        src/xxx/util/*.cpp
        src/xxx/thread/*.cpp)
LIST(REMOVE_ITEM CORE_SRC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/xxx/io/BzipStream.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/xxx/io/GzipStream.cpp)

# This works
ADD_LIBRARY(xxx-core STATIC ${CORE_SRC})
# This doesn't
#ADD_LIBRARY(xxx-core SHARED ${CORE_SRC})
```

The error message is:

```
[100%] Linking CXX shared library libxxxdb-core.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_mpool_get_global", referenced from:
      xxx::mpoolxx<xxx::alloc_to_mpool_bridge<xxx::mpoolxx<long>, 1>::MemBlock>::get_vtab() in trb_cxx.cpp.o
  "_sfixed_mpool_destroy", referenced from:
      xxx::fixed_mpool_wrapper<24>::~fixed_mpool_wrapper() in trb_cxx.cpp.o
  "_sfixed_mpool_init", referenced from:
      xxx::fixed_mpool_wrapper<24>::fixed_mpool_wrapper() in trb_cxx.cpp.o
  "_trb_destroy", referenced from:
      xxx::trbstrmap_imp<int, unsigned char, &(xxx_trb_compare_less_tag), xxx::mpoolxx<long>, 0, 16>::~trbstrmap_imp() in trb_cxx.cpp.o
      xxx::trbtab<int const, std::__1::pair<int const, int>, 0, &(xxx_trb_compare_less_tag), xxx::fixed_mpoolxx<long>, 0, 16>::~trbtab() in trb_cxx.cpp.o
  "_trb_erase", referenced from:
      xxx::trbtab<int const, std::__1::pair<int const, int>, 0, &(xxx_trb_compare_less_tag), xxx::fixed_mpoolxx<long>, 0, 16>::erase(int const&) in trb_cxx.cpp.o
      xxx::trbtab<int const, std::__1::pair<int const, int>, 0, &(xxx_trb_compare_less_tag), xxx::fixed_mpoolxx<long>, 0, 16>::erase(xxx::trb_iterator<std::__1::pair<int const, int>, 16, 0>) in trb_cxx.cpp.o
  "_trb_iter_first", referenced from:
      xxx::trbtab<int const, std::__1::pair<int const, int>, 0, &(xxx_trb_compare_less_tag), xxx::fixed_mpoolxx<long>, 0, 16>::begin() const in trb_cxx.cpp.o
  "_trb_iter_next", referenced from:
      xxx::trb_iterator<std::__1::pair<int const, int>, 16, 0>::operator++() in trb_cxx.cpp.o
  "_trb_probe", referenced from:
      xxx::trbtab<int const, std::__1::pair<int const, int>, 0, &(xxx_trb_compare_less_tag), xxx::fixed_mpoolxx<long>, 0, 16>::insert(std::__1::pair<int const, int> const&) in trb_cxx.cpp.o
      xxx::trbmap<int, int, &(xxx_trb_compare_less_tag), xxx::fixed_mpoolxx<long>, 0, 16>::operator[](int const&) in trb_cxx.cpp.o
  "_trb_probe_node", referenced from:
      xxx::trbstrmap_imp<int, unsigned char, &(xxx_trb_compare_less_tag), xxx::mpoolxx<long>, 0, 16>::probe_raw(char const*, unsigned long, char const*) in trb_cxx.cpp.o
  "_trb_vtab_init", referenced from:
      xxx::trbxx_vtab_init_by_cxx_type(trb_vtab*, field_type_t, int (*)(trb_vtab const*, trb_tree const*, void const*, void const*), int (*)(trb_vtab const*, trb_tree const*, void const*, void const*)) in trb_cxx.cpp.o
      xxx::trbxx_vtab_init(trb_vtab*, field_type_t, int (*)(trb_vtab const*, trb_tree const*, void const*, void const*)) in trb_cxx.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: A static library is pretty much a collection of object files, it is not really linked, and you won't get a linker error creating it. Depending on the platform, a shared library may need to have all external symbols resolved when linking. That's the situation in Windows; when creating a Windows dll, you would need to link against the libraries that provide all these symbols that you see in the error message. Not sure how it works for Mac, but it may be the same.

Answer (score 1):

No linkage happens in the creation of a static library because a static library
is not produced by the linker: it is simply an archive of object files created
with the archiver [`ar`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/ar/). So there can't
be any undefined references or other linkage errors when you create a static library,
just like there can't be if you create a `.tar` or `.zip` archive of object files. 
See [static-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-libraries/info),

A shared library, like a program, *is* produced by the linker and the Mac OS/Darwin
linker (unlike the GNU/Linux linker) by default does not permit undefined symbol
references in a shared library.

You have two options:

You can specify all the libraries that `xxx-core` depends upon to its linkage,
with [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/target_link_libraries.html)

Or, you can override the linker's default behaviour with the linkage option
[`-undefined=dynamic_lookup`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/ld/), indicating
that undefined references in the shared library are to be resolved by the loader at runtime.
In your CMakeLists.txt, use [`set_target_properties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/set_target_properties.html)
after you have defined the `xxx-core` target:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(xxx-core SHARED ${CORE_SRC})
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(xxx-core LINK_FLAGS Wl,-undefined=dynamic_lookup)
```